# Some problems when using omnet++

Tags: c++, windows, omnet++, sumo, inet

I am trying to use the omnet++ following tutorials on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCs-K9AkDrQ&list=PLaBPUIXZ8s4AwAk5EelikvvyG4EzX2hpx

When I build the VANETTutorials in video3， it failed. I following every steps in the video，

Omnet++ version：6.0.3，
inet：4.5.2

following errors：[enter image description here]

```
`ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: inet::OperationalMixin<omnetpp::cSimpleModule>::numInitStages() const
>>> referenced by ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetApplicationBase.o:(vtable for inet::ApplicationBase)
>>> referenced by ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetApplicationBase.o:(vtable for inet::OperationalBase)
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:121: ../out/gcc-debug/src/libVANETTutorials_dbg.dll] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/e/inet/VANETTutorials/src'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
"make MODE=debug all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete. `
```

I wonder whether the warnings in figure have influence on it. Is there a conflict between the versions of Omnet++ and inet. How do I solve it?[enter image description here]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSV0M.png)

Answer (score 0):

With the lack of information provided, it is quite hard to give you a definite answer to exactly what is going wrong, but looking at the error message that you provided, it looks like you are trying to define a function that has not been declared.

This could be that you are trying to call a function without the class or template scope, or that you simply forgot to declare the function in your header file.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to resolve the issue by using the recommended versions for OMNeT++, INET, and Veins. (For anyone else experiencing a similar problem, you can check if your version of OMNeT++ matches with INET and Veins on this website: http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/instant-veins/)